# How to get the ipod path or save the document files path ipod?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am working in iphone technology. How to get the path in iphone or ipod.
I get the path only particular app.What is the coding for get the full documents directory.

I am using following code,that is work and display for particular directory

```
- (void)listFiles {
    int           count, i;

    NSError       *err;

    NSArray       *directoryContent;

    NSArray       *myPathList        =  NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [myPathList  objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(documentsDirectory);

    directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error: err];

    count = (int)[directoryContent count];

    for (i=0; i<count; i++)

    {

        self.listData = directoryContent;
        //[directoryContent release];
 //  tableview = [tableview stringByAppendingString:[directoryContent objectAtIndex:i]];

       // tableview = [tableview stringByAppendingString:@"\n"];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On iOS each app is restricted to an application sandbox.  That sandbox restricts your application from accessing any portion of the filesystem other than what Apple allows you to access.  So the following code would produce the Documents directory for your specific application, but in general there is not any "full documents directory".  In other words there is no way to access documents belonging to another application.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```